# JpegBitmapEncoder cannot access closed stream

Tags: c#

I have a BitmapSource loaded from a byte array this way:

```
BitmapSource bitmap = null;

using (var stream = new MemoryStream(bytes))
{
  var decoder = new JpegBitmapDecoder(stream, BitmapCreateOptions.None, BitmapCacheOption.None);
      bitmap = decoder.Frames[0];
      stream.Flush();
}

return bitmap;
```

When I'm trying to write this as an JPEG to disk, it only throws an error:

[image]

Any ideas here? Other ways of writing the image to disk?

Comment: As it says... image, encoder, or the bitmapframe has been disposed.. Images in .NET are using non managed resources, if you dispose them, the windows resources are flushed, and so you can not access the data anymore.

Comment: You need to write return statement inside the using block. Closed stream can not be accessed by anything.